# FirestoreRecyclerAdapter not displaying newly added FireStore data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I have a custom FirestoreRecyclerAdapter and it correctly displays all the items currently stored in the Firestore Database.  However when I enter a new item into the database the adapter does not display the newly added item from the database.  If i go back a screen and open the recyclerview again I can see the "newly" added data.  How can I make the recycler view display the newly added Firestore data?

Expected: New data shows up at the top of the recylcerview
Result: New data does not display at all in recyclerview

Problem: New data won't display in RecyclerView

```
 CollectionReference messagesCollectionRef = db.collection(MESSAGES);
    Query query = messagesCollectionRef.whereEqualTo(GROUPID, groupid).orderBy(TIMESTAMP, Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<MessagesResponse> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<MessagesResponse>()
            .setQuery(query, MessagesResponse.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new MessagesAdapter(options, progressBar, messagesList, userid);
    adapter.startListening();
    messagesList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my adapter

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<MessagesResponse, MessagesHolder> {
private static final String USERS = "users";
private static final String IMAGE = "image";
private static final String MESSAGE = "message";
private FirebaseFirestore db;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private RecyclerView messagesList;
private String userid;

public MessagesAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<MessagesResponse> options, ProgressBar progressBar, RecyclerView messagesList, String userid) {
    super(options);

    this.progressBar = progressBar;
    this.messagesList = messagesList;
    this.userid = userid;
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
}

@Override
public void onDataChanged() {
    messagesList.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(getItemCount() - 1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessagesHolder holder, int position, @NonNull MessagesResponse model) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //set user profile pic
    setProfilePic(holder, model);

    //image message
    if(model.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(IMAGE)) {
        displayImage(model.getMessage(), holder);
    }
    //text message
    if(model.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(MESSAGE)) {
        holder.message.setText(model.getMessage());
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MessagesHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_list_item,
            parent, false);
    return new MessagesHolder(v);
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by creating an index on the firebase console on my groupid and timestamp fields.  This is apparently something used for creating complex queries.

Here is the documentation on creating an index.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing